# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=L$ show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$

Tags: analysis

> Let $f:(0,\infty) \to R$ be differentiable. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=L$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$. (Hint: Write $f(x) = e^xf(x)/e^x$ and use l’Hopital’s Rule.)

My working for $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$:

For $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$, I let $f(x) = e^xf(x)/e^x$ and applied quotient rule which then cancels off $e^{2x}$ and I'm left with $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x)-f(x))$. Can I then equate this with $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(f(x)+f'(x)\right) - \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ which then gives $L-L=0$? Is this step correct?

Comment: Hi @eee! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$). Also, please show your working so far :)

Comment: Well, did you try computing $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ using the Hint (Note, L'Hôpital's rule can be used since the denominator of $e^xf(x)/e^x$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$)?

Comment: i am stuck at getting limx→∞f(x)..

Comment: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{e^xf(x)\over e^x}\ \buildrel{\text LH}\over= \ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\bigl(e^xf(x)\bigr)'\over (e^x)' }=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{e^xf(x)+e^x f'(x)\over e^x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\bigl(f(x)+f'(x)\bigr).$$

Comment: OH I made a careless mistake product rule involves + and not - how careless can i be! thanks a lot david :)

Comment: @David Mitra: For your argument you have to assume that $L\ne 0$, take for example $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Comment: @gammatester I don't see your point...

Comment: i dont think there's a need to assume L≠ 0..

Comment: @David Mitra: You must have $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}e^x f(x) = \infty\,$ to apply L'Hôpital in the given form, which is not the case for $f(x)=e^{-x},\,$ i.e. $L=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra for lim f′(x) = 0, i used quotient rule which then cancels off e^2x and i'm left with lim(f(x)+f'(x)-f(x)). can i then equate this with lim(f(x)+f'(x))-lim(f(x)) which then gives L-L=0? is this step correct?

Comment: @gammatester No. The rule applies whenever the denominator has infinite limit. It does not matter what the numerator is doing (the limit of the numerator need not even exist). This is mentioned on the Wiki page as a note in the "General proof" section, as well as several Analysis texts. E.g., Bartle and Sherberts'. (For some unfathomable reason, this form is not mentioned in most calculus texts.)

Comment: @David Mitra: I do not doubt your result, but the Wiki pages and e.g.
http://planetmath.org/lhopitalsrule or http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=L%27Hospital_rule&oldid=14236 all assume the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or 
$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. I will look into some off-line sources. There is no need to continue this discussion.

Comment: I have difficulty proving the second part of the question where lim f'(x)=0, and I think my working above is wrong. kindly enlighten me thank you. :)

Comment: @gammatester See Theorem 7.1, page 127, from [these notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf) of Pete L. Clark. The proof there is taken from baby Rudin.

Comment: @David Mitra: Thank you. Meanwhile I found the mention note on the Wiki page too.

Comment: Hmm,I'm still stuck at proving the part where limf'(x)=0, my working seemed 'illegal', any headstart?

Comment: Another related post: [If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) - xf'(x)$ exists, does $\lim_{x \to\infty} f'(x)$ exist as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3776315)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have function $f$, and it's given that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + f'(x)) = L.$

We'll **assume** that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0.$

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0.$, then we can rewrite:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + f'(x)) = L$$ as  $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + 0) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L.$$

If we'll prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + f'(x))$, then we've proved that $f'(x) = 0$.

Using the hint you gave, we'll turn $f(x)$ into $\frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x}$ and using `LHopital's` rule that says:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)}$$.

In our case, $$g(x) = {e^xf(x)} \text{ and } h(x) = e^x. $$

Let's start:

$$1. \text{Turn to suggested form:} \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x}.$$

$$2. \text{Apply LHopital's rule: differentiate both numerator and denumerator}:$$

$$ \lim \frac{(e^xf(x))'}{(e^x)'} = \lim = \frac{e^x f(x) + e^x f'x}{e^x} = \lim (f(x) + f'(x)).$$

We've got that $f(x) = f(x) + f'(x)$ that meets out assumation.

Therefore, $f'(x) = 0$.

Proven.

Comment: Well you have to prove that $f'(x)=0$...

Comment: @user1798362 sorry I don't really get your point..

Comment: @Umberto: But in this case i cannot use definition of derivative correct? because x tends to infinity..

Comment: Well you are actually (altough not explicitly) working with two limits. One in your derivative definition and one for $x$ going to infinity. The hint given is very useful, but mathematically speaking, an ugly way of solving the problem (estetically speaking...).

Comment: @eee I have edited my answer.

Comment: @user1798362: did you include the bracket? the question is lim (f(x)+f'(x)) = L. did you mean the same thing in your first line?

Comment: @eee It doesn't matter when there's only `+` and no $\cdot$ or these things. the answer is the same for $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + f'(x)$

Comment: oh ok so are you using lim(f(x)+g(x))=lim f(x) + lim g(x) ?

Comment: @eee this is my write style. I edited the post using the brakets. I meant exactly to the expression you asked.

Comment: ok i used the same working to prove the first part of the question limf(x)=L so am i right to say if i have derived the first part, i can easily obtain the second part?

Comment: @eee You are right

Comment: L = lim (f(x)+f'(x)) = lim(f(x)) + lim(f'(x)) = L + 0, so lim(f'(x))=0?

Comment: @user1798362 it really is that easy to prove the second part? thank you!

Comment: @eee Yes, this is a basic question .. If I helped you, please accept my answer

Comment: is it just press tick will do? sorry i'm new. :)

Comment: @eee Yes :) I glad to be able to help you, can't forget the days I needed this help..

Comment: oh haha thanks a lot! anw actually i have one more question halfway done, do you mind? it's here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648730/fx-cos-x-prove-that-f-is-differentiable-at-these-points-and-not-differe/648744?noredirect=1#648744

Comment: @user1798362: um does this stackexchange allow us to add friends? how do i approach you next time if i have a question? :)

Comment: @eee I'm not as good in Calculus as you think .. it's just a very basic question ..

Answer (score 0):

In case some doubt the condition of application of L'Hopital rule, we can use the discreted substitution version - i.e. Stolz theorem,which states that for two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, if $b_n\rightarrow\infty$ monotonously,then as long as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}$ exists (could be $\pm \infty$),we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}.
\end{align*}
Now suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ is not $L$,then there exists $M>0$, such that for each $X$, there exists $x>X$ such that $|f(x)-L|>M$.Choose monotonous sequence $\{x_n\}\rightarrow \infty$ such that $|f(x_n)-L|>M$.Consider $a_n=e^{x_n}(f(x_n)-L)$ and $b_n=e^{x_n}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{e^{x_n}(f(x_n)-L)-e^{x_{n-1}}(f(x_{n-1})-L)}{e^{x_n}-e^{x_{n-1}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{\xi_n}(f(\xi_n)+f'(\xi_n)-L)}{e^{\xi_n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(\xi_n)+f'(\xi_n)-L\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
So by Stolz theorem we see
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{e^{x_n}(f(x_n)-L)}{e^{x_n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)-L\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
which contradicts that $|f(x_n)-L|$ has a non-zero lower bound.
This may be equivalent to the proof of L'Hopital as the Stolz does, but I think it may resolve the doubt about where L'Hopital rule can apply.