# $f(x) = |\cos x|$ prove that f is differentiable at these points and not differentiable at all other points.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Define $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = |\cos x|$. Determine the set of points where f is differentiable and calculate the derivative of f on this set. Also prove that $f$ is differentiable at these points and not differentiable at all other points.

My working: 
from the graph of $|\cos x|$, we can see that the $|\cos x|$ is differentiable everywhere except at 
points where $x=(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi$, where $k$ is an integer, but this is intuitive, i'm having difficulty giving a proper proof of $|\cos x|$ being differentiable at these points.

Comment: What about go with the definition of the differentiation? Also, is that a homework?

Comment: nope, professor gave f(x)=|sinx|, so i thought of the possibility of changing it to cosx and try practising it, but it seems a bit tricky.

Comment: It is good to draw a graph and see what are the potential points at which the function is not differentiable. Then you could do it by definition. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: I have not time right now, but I think that the definition would work...

Comment: @Poppy is right, I think...

Comment: @Poppy yeah, I found out the graph is non-differentiable at x=(k+$\frac{1}{2}$)pi but I am not very familiar in using the definition..

Comment: I find it hard to believe you'd be given this problem before you've been shown that $g(x)=\cos x$ is differentiable.

Comment: the professor just mentioned that it is clearly obvious cos x is differentiable and proceed to give us |sin x|, which I then changed it to |cos x|

Comment: I was wondering if you could post a solution to this question after having to solve it? I am an undergraduate student, and ponder upon this post and thought it would interesting to know more as I have just start learning the topic on differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. @Poppy has given you the right hint. Consider the two limits
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\dfrac{|\cos{(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}|-0}{h}
$$
and
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}\dfrac{|\cos{(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}|-0}{h}
$$
for the function to be differentiable the two limits must be equal. Consider them. Since in the first $h>0$ and in the second $h<0$ you can take the absolute value away (the nominator does not change sign). You will see that the two limits have a different sign (since h in the denominator change the sign) and therefore the function is not differentiable at that point.

Generally speaking when you have a cusp (is the right english term)? Your derivative (the slope of the tangent) will suddenly jump in value, often changing sign.

EDITED: to answer the OP question. When can you take the absolute value away? If the argument of the absolute value is positive (let's consider only real number) then you can take away the absolute value, if the argument is negative then you can take it away but you have to add a minus. Some examples:
$$
|3|=3
$$
$$
|-3|=3
$$
or more generally 
$$
A>0 \Rightarrow |A|=A
$$
$$
A<0 \Rightarrow |A|=-A
$$
Is it clearer now?

EDIT 2: to answer the questions in the comments on why is differentiable in all other points.

Let's consider only the range of angles $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ for the moment. In this case the $\cos (x)$ is positive and therefore our definition of derivative can written without the absolute value
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{cos(x+h)-cos(x)}{h}
$$
this limit does not depend on the fact that $h\to 0^+$ or $h\to 0^-$. It exists and is the well known derivative of the $\cos$ function. 
When you consider the range of angles $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ you can take the absolute value away adding a minus sign (since the $\cos$ is now negative). But then again the limit does not depend if $h$ reaches zero from the right or the left.

Comment: yeah I knew about this concept, but I always have difficulty with the absolute sign. why is it that we can take absolute away?

Comment: Take, for example, $k=0$. If $h>0$ then $\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}<0$. If $h<0$ then $\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}>0$.

Comment: this doesn't work for example if i take h=6, then cos($\frac{pi}{2}+h$) is > 0

Comment: or should i take h=0.00001 that is close to 0?

Comment: You need to take it close to $0$. Remember that in your limit you have $h$ in your denominator and _that_ changes the sign! I slightly edited my answer to make it more precise and clear. I hope is ok for you now and that you can understand the reason why is not differentiable.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please consider marking it as answer so that other know that they will find an answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much!
so to prove the graph is differentiable at other points can i just differentiate cos x which gives -sinx and just state it's differentiable?

Comment: In theory you should show that the limit (the definition we have discussed before) at an arbitrary point $x$ (excluding the ones you have already found) is the same coming from left and from right. Is actually relatively easy then.

Comment: yeah i get the idea of using the definition of derivative to prove both the left-hand and right-hand limits are equal,

Comment: i tried when h>0, lim($\frac{cos(x+h)-cosx}{h}$)...

Comment: @Umberto: i started with the definition of derivative but how do i prove they are equal? since i cannot do anything with the cos(x+h)-cosx

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: @Umberto I understood partly, except for the last part why is it that when I consider the range of angles [π/2,3π/2] the limit does not depend if h reaches zero from the right or the left? there is now a negative sign..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12636/discussion-between-umberto-and-eee)

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\text{in our case}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{|\cos{(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}|-0}{h}$

Can you solve this limit?

Comment: yeah I got that step, after which do I use L'hopital's rule to evaluate?

Comment: Remember, a limit to be defined must be equal when considering reaching it from the left and from the right. What happens to your limits (the definition of derivative) when you are approaching the limit from the left and the right? Does this hint help you?

Comment: Yeah, you can, but first you have to get rid of the absolute value. To do this you have to see what happens when h is positive and when h is negative.

Comment: @Umberto said it more precisely.