# Let $f$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$.Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0$,then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

My attempt:

When both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ $\to 0$ when $x\to \infty$ then the problem is trivial. But, the problem is I cannot do anything more than the trivial case. I definitely realise that if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0$ is true. But, I cannot really prove the converse. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show that as $x \to \infty$, $\lim f(x) = L$ and $\lim f'(x) = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648652/show-that-as-x-to-infty-lim-fx-l-and-lim-fx-0) (this is the same question but more general. $L=0$ corresponds to this question)

Comment: "I definitely realise that.." If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ then it does *not* follow that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) + f'(x) = 0$. $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @Winther Yes, I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Apply L'Hospital's rule to $$\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}.$$

Comment: The exponent of $e$ is too small for me to see.

Comment: Right. I realise you are very correct!  Thank you.

Comment: There is subtlety to the logic here though; notice that in using L'Hospital's rule, we must assume that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule requires that both the numerator and denominator terms approach, in this case, infinity. You're trying to prove that $f$ goes to zero. If it does, then how does one know that $e^xf(x)$  still goes to infinity? Or perhaps $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^xf(x)$ does not exist (e.g., $f(x)=\sin(x)$).

Comment: @Dr.MV L'Hospital's Rule does NOT require both terms approach to infinity, though its usual form is what you mentioned. The same is true for a related theorem of Stolz. By the way, as for $\frac{0}{0}$, BOTH terms should approach to zero!

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic See the comment above. We only need the denominator approaches to infinity.

Comment: @EclipseSun That's simply not true. Consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=0$. The denominator approaches infinity, but this clearly doesn't work if you differentiate a la L'Hospital.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic Consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-\sin (x)}{x}=0$. Be careful when using L'Hospital.

Comment: @EclipseSun That's exactly the point. We need to be careful when using L'Hospital. I gave an example where the denominator approaches $\infty$ but L'Hospital's rule does not apply. Your example is a perfectly good example of the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ to which nobody will object.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0$$
I used L'hosptal rule.

Comment: Lorence.  L'Hospital's Rule requires that both the numerator and denominator terms approach, in this case, infinity. You're trying to prove that $f$ goes to zero. If it does, then how does one know that $e^xf(x)$  still goes to infinity? Or perhaps $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^xf(x)$ does not exist (e.g., $f(x)=\sin(x)$).

Comment: @Dr.MV   Sorry to say that  L'Hospital's Rule doesn't require both the numerator and denominator terms approach infinity,we only need denominator terms approaches infinity and can't be zero.